# How do I play with my friend in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

My and a friend wanted to start playing Guild Wars 2 together. Both of us selected the same server and created our characters. Once in-game, we opened the Contacts menu with <kbd>Y</kbd>, sent each other a friend request, and joined a party.

However, despite being friends with each other and joining the same party, neither one of us could see each other in-game. [A few posts online](http://www.guildwars2guru.com:80/topic/52666-how-do-i-join-my-friends-instance/) said I should be able to join my friend's instance by selecting "*Join server*", but when I right click my friend's portrait this doesn't appear as an option.

How can I start playing Guild Wars 2 with a friend? Do we need to complete the tutorial before playing together?

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like you were not on the same instance of the map, once in the same party, goto the same map. Then click on your friend in the party and click Join in instance (name of map). Should be called something like that.

I think that you have to finish the tutorial before you'll both be out in the main world, this should take 10-15 minutes.

A map instance is a way that allows a lot of players to be on the same map without it over loading. Each instance allows (iirc 125 - 150 people??) But before that cap a new instance is created (automatically) and people are placed in it.

You'll find when joining large groups for world events etc.. that they're greyed out on the list of party members, right click on one of them and join in there instance, if the map is full it'll say so.

This is the only way to "switch" instances, making your own or trying to get to a specific one isn't allowed.

Another reason could be:

Did you both join the same region? i.e NA, EU, China (iirc)

If one of you is on EU, they'll have to transfer to NA to be able to play together (should be free) NA only accounts can NOT transfer to EU.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out we spawned in different locations because we picked different races.

Thankfully I had an old character which was the same race my friend picked, so I was able to fast travel to a waypoint in their area with my new character. (I had her pull up the map with M and asked her where her character was.)

I’m not sure how I would have found them otherwise.

Comment: Just curious, if you were already a player, wouldn't you have already been aware of the different race stating locations?

Comment: @ForceGaia I played briefly back in 2013 when they had a [2 day free weekend](https://www.guildwars2.com/en/news/register-today-for-the-guild-wars-2-free-trial-on-august-23-25/). I hadn’t even remembered I had an account until trying to sign up again.

Comment: ah, that makes sense now. As the tone fo the question was tha you were both new, but when you said you had another character that just sounded odd.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing on [Worlds in the same region](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/World#List_of_worlds) and are in a party together, you can use the [starting zone waypoints](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Waypoint#New_players) to travel to each other.

The game will try to put you on the same map automatically. If the map is full,
you can join another map by right-clicking your friend's party icon or name and selecting "Join In" while in the same zone.